# value not inserting in wordpress table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to insert a custom form value developed by me in a template file. So that I created a customer_info table in wordprress database. Is it right way to do?

here is code what I tried so far:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 global $wpdb;
echo $q=$_GET['q']; 
$a=$_POST['name'];
$b=$_POST['lname'];
$c=$_POST['email'];
$d=$_POST['mobile'];
$e=$_POST['phone'];
$f=$_POST['accom'];
$g=$_POST['adress'];
$h=$_POST['remark'];
$wpdb->insert( 'customer_info', array( 'post_id' => $q, 'name' => $a,'lname' => $b, 'email' => $c,'mobile' => $d, 'phone' => $e,'adress' => $g, 'remark' => $h  ), array( '%d', '%d','%s', '%s' ,'%s', '%s' ,'%s', '%s'  ) );
}

?>
```

Why its not working? while by same process I inserted two form value on localhost.

As in core php I know how to debug etc, so please tell me how can I do that in wordpress becouse wordpress have its own wpdb classes for database manipulation.

**here is my html form**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<table width="50%" align="left">
<h3>Customer Info</h3>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Name</td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Last Name</td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Email</td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">mobile</td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="mobile" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Phone</td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td valign="top">Address</td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="adress" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">Remark</td><td valign="top"><input type="textarea" name="remark" /></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Click for continue</td><td valign="top"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

If anything I missed please feel free to ask.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `echo $wpdb->last_query` to print query.

Comment: What is the issue ? Can you define it now?

Comment: I dont know, when I hit on submit button it redirecting to Error 404, page not found while I dont have anything in form action. I am not good enough in wordpress. So do you have any idea....

Comment: Can you post your form HTML?

Comment: okay...see my upadates.

Comment: Can you give the another value for name attribute to `<input type="text" name="name" />`? And pls give me the your echoed value of `echo $wpdb->last_query`.

Comment: I tried to echo last query but I am not getting anything, redirecting to error 404 page.  Okay I am changing name attribute...

Comment: 'INSERT INTO `customer_info` (`post_id`,`name`,`lname`,`email`,`mobile`,`phone`,`adress`,`remark`) VALUES (0,'','','','','','','')`

Comment: Bindiya if I dont fill form value then it showing up this otherwise going to Error 404 page....

Comment: yesss....blank value inserted..... :)

Comment: Use `'%s'` for name field in array.

Comment: Thanks a lot bindiya, now its working.....can you tell me what couse for that problem. you can mention it in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try for error like this

```
1) Enable database error display via $wpdb->show_errors()
2) Check what query is being formed and run via $wpdb->last_query
```

`name` field in your case is a string and you have defined it as integer in your insert array, use `'%s'` for that instead of `%d`.
Also use different `name` attributes for inputs because `name` is reserved word,may be this be a cause.

Comment: yes name attribute was problem, as  I changed it my query is working fine.... Thanks for your support and time... :)